# Unable to play a video with CCL because of NullPointerException

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I am trying to play the following video 
https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/videos/A2798484D41041440198208659456_1391272876299b1ffbbdfb5.mp4_YTmPg6EwCUKAbbQtWT3BQPPxzQj290VxAG5VAywks7da5SRCoUqrp3iuhiFfOlDL.mp4?versionId=XMG6Bt70r4InoH1BonmNYZtgZFkERjm9

with the Cast Companion Library (latest version from this morning), and I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.google.android.gms.cast.MediaMetadata.hashCode(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.Arrays.hashCode(Arrays.java:1260)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.ee.hashCode(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.cast.MediaInfo.hashCode(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Object.toString(Object.java:332)
            at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:202)
            at com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.cast.VideoCastManager.loadMedia(VideoCastManager.java:1026)
            at com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.cast.VideoCastManager.loadMedia(VideoCastManager.java:1010)
```

I am able to play various other videos with the exact same code. It appears that `LOGD(TAG, "loadMedia: " + media);` is getting the hashcode of MediaInfo which is missing something (probably my title in this one video, also the image urls).

EDIT: with a small workaround passing a fake title I got the video to play just fine.

Comment: Please let me know which fields are missing that are causing the NPE in your case.

Comment: When I added a non null title it started working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this issue will appear in the next release of the framework.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem and it was solved as soon as I added a value for MediaMetadata.KEY_STUDIO.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem until I had values for both MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE AND MediaMetadata.KEY_STUDIO.